# How to use other class enum properties in Qml

Tags: qml, qt6

Given is a class `ClassA` which contains an enum:

```
class ClassA : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    
public:
    enum EnumClassA {
    };
    Q_ENUM(EnumClassA)
    
};
```

A second class has a property of `ClassA::EnumClassA`:

```
#include <ClassA.h>
class ClassB : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    
    Q_PROPERTY(ClassA::EnumClassA value READ ...)
public:
    
};
```

This works in Qml (meaning the property `value` can be used in Qml), but when using qmlint/qmlsc compiler the following message is shown:

```
error: Could not compile binding for value: Cannot generate efficient code for content pointer of non-QVariant wrapper type double of ClassB::value with type ClassA::EnumClassA
```

A dirty fix could be this:

```
// replace "Q_PROPERTY(ClassA::EnumClassA value READ ...)" with:
Q_PROPERTY(int value READ ...)
```

but it would be much nicer to keep the type in the property.

Is it possible to modify the enum so that it can be compiled?

Regards,

Comment: You have a typo. You wrote `ClassA:EnumClassA`, when it should be `ClassA::EnumClassA`. Is that the source of the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately the typo was just a copy&paste thing and is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Okay. Why does the error message say `type double`? Am I misreading that? There's no double in the code you are showing.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Maybe it is a bug in the qmlint/qmlsc compiler.